# PDO Parameterized Query - Reuse named placeholders?

Tags: php, pdo

In essence, I have a value that I have to call a couple times in my SQL query. Thus, is it possible to reuse the same named placeholder in the statement e.g. 
`SELECT :Param FROM Table WHERE Column = :Param`, then simply bindValue(":Param"), and have the value be there for both :Params?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?  PDO::prepare says yes and PDOStatement::execute says you may need to close the db cursor dependent upon the driver.

Comment: I tried it, I kept getting an error, but I figured I was doing something else wrong. Was couldn't find anything in the docs (was looking at PDO::bindParam). Found it in PDO::prepare though,thanks for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: Actually, the first part `SELECT :Param` that is impossible; you can't bind tables/columns, consult http://stackoverflow.com/q/182287/. *However,* you could do `$Param = "column"; SELECT $Param...`

Comment: Do you think you could award me with the answer is that possible? The current accepted states it is not possible but it is with my solution

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) states that "you cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a prepared statement", so I guess that's a no then.

Comment: The docs are not completely correct. If `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` is `true`, PDO *DOES* support reusing named parameter markers.

Comment: It looks like someone updated the docs. It now says "You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on."

Comment: You're partially right. However `SELECT :Param` is impossible, since you can't bind tables/columns. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/182287/

Comment: but then pdo turns everything into a string if you use `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`

Answer (score 9):

You can if you set `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = true`.

E.g. `$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);`.

If you're using Laravel you can set this in an `options` array in `config/database.php`. e.g. `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true`

Answer (score 3):

Apart from reuse, the main issue here is that you are trying to dynamically change col names.

This answer posted by an anonymous user on http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php :

> To those wondering why adding quotes to around a placeholder is wrong,
>   and why you can't use placeholders for table or column names:
>
> There is a common misconception about how the placeholders in prepared
>   statements work: they are not simply substituted in as (escaped)
>   strings, and the resulting SQL executed. Instead, a DBMS asked to
>   "prepare" a statement comes up with a complete query plan for how it
>   would execute that query, including which tables and indexes it would
>   use, which will be the same regardless of how you fill in the
>   placeholders.
>
> The plan for "SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE id = :value" will be the
>   same whatever you substitute for ":value", but the seemingly similar
>   "SELECT name FROM :table WHERE id = :value" cannot be planned, because
>   the DBMS has no idea what table you're actually going to select from.
>
> Even when using "emulated prepares", PDO cannot let you use
>   placeholders anywhere, because it would have to work out what you
>   meant: does "Select :foo From some_table" mean ":foo" is going to be a
>   column reference, or a literal string?

When your query is using a dynamic column reference, you should be explicitly white-listing the columns you know to exist on the table, e.g. using a switch statement with an exception thrown in the default: clause.

Answer (score 2):

Many queries like yours can be rewritten to use only one placeholder.

```
SELECT :Param FROM Table WHERE Column = :Param
```

would be the same as

```
SELECT Column FROM Table WHERE Column = :Param
```

But sometimes it's not that simple. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE first_name LIKE :Param
   OR last_name  LIKE :Param
   OR biography  LIKE :Param
```

In such case you could reuse the parameter value storing it in a cross joined derived table (subquery in FROM clause):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM my_table t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT :Param as Param) AS x
WHERE first_name LIKE x.Param
   OR last_name  LIKE x.Param
   OR biography  LIKE x.Param
```

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, there are quite some workarounds:

1. Use different placeholders whilst providing them the same value.
2. Rewrite your query so that only unique placeholders are required.
3. Set `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to `true`

If the above is not possible nor desirable, there is another elegant way to solve this, by using variables in SQL:

```
DECLARE @MyVariable AS INT = :value;
SELECT column_x FROM table WHERE column_y = @MyVariable OR column_z = @MyVariable;
```

Then prepare this statement by just assigning `value`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround:

```
  function search($criteria) {

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table
        WHERE column_1 like CONCAT('%', :criteria1, '%') 
           OR column_2 like CONCAT('%', :criteria2, '%') 
           OR column_3 like CONCAT('%', :criteria3, '%')  
     ";

     $stmt =  $this->db->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->bindParam(':criteria1', $criteria);
     $stmt->bindParam(':criteria2', $criteria);
     $stmt->bindParam(':criteria3', $criteria);
     $stmt->execute();
     return($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
  }
```

In summary, use different placeholders with the same criteria.

Comment: [Less code, more readable SQL](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/e09c495943d9ea91f56d3943d86296b6/)