# How do I insert an array of id into database MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I'm trying to insert an array of IDs into a database table, but at the moment it only inserts 1 row when it's meant to do multiple rows. My array of IDs contains just (filmid) Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
$pm = "2";
$id = "2";             

if($stmt1->execute())
{
    $films=array();
    foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $key=>$product)
    {
        array_push($films, $product['filmid']);
        $f_id  = implode(",", $films);
        $stmt2 = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `filmPurchase` (`fpid`, `payid`, `filmid`, `shopid`, `custid`, `price`) VALUES (NULL, :id, :f_id, :pm, :pm, '8')");
        $stmt2->bindParam('pm',$pm);
        $stmt2->bindParam('id',$id);
        $stmt2->bindParam('f_id',$f_id);
        $stmt2->execute();
    }

}
```

I've tried to loop over the array with:

```
foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $key=>$product)
{
    var_dump($key);
    var_dump($product);
}
```

This is what outputted:

```
int(29) array(4) { ["qty"]=> int(1) ["filmtitle"]=> string(45) "The Lord of 
the Rings: The Return of the King" ["filmid"]=> string(2) "29" ["price"]=> 
float(6.99) }
```

Comment: You only have 1 item in your array. `$f_id` should also be bound when you insert it.

Comment: 3 issues I see immediately: you don't define `$pm` or `$id` in the code shown; if you're going to use prepare, you should bind all the variables (looking at `'$f_id'`), and you can't use the same bound parameter twice (`:pm, :pm`). You have to rename one of them.

Comment: I've made those changes also I've added the defined ids. But still doing the same thing.

Comment: You may also want to rethink your query. Your loop is going to push `"The Lord of  the Rings: The Return of the King"` on the first loop, `"The Lord of  the Rings: The Return of the King", "The Lord of  the Rings: The Two Towers",` on the second loop...

Comment: @aynber it's possible to use same parameter twice.

Comment: Another thing you can do is log on each loop. Also check for [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) during the process.

Comment: @Asenar [Only if `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` is set to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432084/pdo-parameterized-query-reuse-named-placeholders). Since that part of the code is not shown, we can't be sure. It's better to try to not reuse parameters, though, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

If your placeholder is `:id` and `:pm` (as in `prepare()`) then you must use `:id` in `bindParam()`

[See php documentation](http://%20http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Comment: aren't they doing that now? I think you should go over their code again, and look at the comments under it.

Comment: You're right, in the mean time, someone commented about `f_id` and the author edited his code, so I removed this mention