# How to bound params multiple time twice

Tags: php, pdo

In this case I bound one named parameter, `:var`.

```
$var = 'John Doe';
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * from `users` where user = :var");
$query->bindParam(":var", $var);
$query->execute();
```

But now, I need to bind the single named parameter twice,

```
$var = 'John Doe';
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * from `users` as u left join `user_group` as ug on u.user_id = ug.user_id where u.user = :var and ug.user_name = :var");
$query->bindParam(":var", $var);
$query->execute();
```

So, my question is that can i set `bindParam` single time or multi-time ?

Comment: Just give it a try and see if it works with one, however, IIRC, it will throw up an error if you did it with less number of variables in `bindParam` than your query.

Comment: You aren't using `mysqli` please keep the tags appropriate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432084/pdo-parameterized-query-reuse-named-placeholders.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#example-1046
check first example

Comment: @Jaydp I can't see where the OP is meant to be looking in that link, can you clarify what specifically in the first example?