# PHP PDO: Can't bind value to multiple variables?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to execute a query that joins several tables using the same foreign key via the below query but it returns false.

```
$question_id = 11406;

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT q.question_attempts_permitted, q.question_range, a.answer_text, r.attempt_count 
                           FROM checkup_questions q, checkup_answers a, user_responses r 
                           WHERE a.question_id=:question_id AND q.question_id=:question_id AND r.question_id=:question_id");
$query->bindValue(':question_id', $question_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

However, if I inject the question_id directly the query returns the desired result.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT q.question_attempts_permitted, q.question_range, a.answer_text, r.attempt_count 
                       FROM checkup_questions q, checkup_answers a, user_responses r 
                       WHERE a.question_id=11406 AND q.question_id=11406 AND r.question_id=11406");
$query->execute();
```

Is there some limitation with the bindValue interface that causes the first query to fail while the second one returns as expected?

Comment: You can't use same placeholder more than once. Full stop.

Comment: ah ok. so how does one handle a situation in which the same value needs to be referenced multiple times such as the above example?

Comment: Use different placeholders, isn't it? Or a correct `JOIN` in the query.

Comment: In this specific case: `WHERE a.question_id=:question_id AND q.question_id=a.question_id AND r.question_id=a.question_id`. You should though use `JOIN` syntax - Then the solution might be obvious.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - thanks I see the issue now.

Comment: @u_mulder - thank you as well. I did not understand what you meant by correct JOIN at first but I get it now.

Comment: See: [PDO Parameterized Query - Reuse named placeholders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432084/pdo-parameterized-query-reuse-named-placeholders)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query text should be rewritten using `JOIN`:

```
$query = $db->prepare("
    SELECT q.question_attempts_permitted, q.question_range, a.answer_text, r.attempt_count 
    FROM checkup_questions q 
    JOIN checkup_answers a ON a.question_id = q.question_id
    JOIN user_responses r ON r.question_id = q.question_id
    WHERE q.question_id=:question_id
");
// you can provide placeholder without `:`
$query->bindValue('question_id', $question_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

Here you have only one placeholder.