# Prepared statements, SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, on-duplicate-key

I'm trying to write a query to insert/update a table and it's my first time using prepared statements, I'm receiving the error `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number` but from what I can see I'm passing all the columns/values required.

(I'm trying to do this without using `bindParam` as in example #2 [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php))

This is just a test for now, I plan on making it dynamic once I've actually got a query working.

```
$data_test = [
            ':event_id' => 3354,
            ':event'    => 'TESTESTEST',
            ':staff_booking_id' => 27255,
            ':is_read' => 'yes',
            ':priority' => 'medium'
        ];

        $q = "INSERT INTO events(event_id, event, staff_booking_id, is_read, priority) 
              VALUES(:event_id, :event, :staff_booking_id, :is_read, :priority) 
              ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE event_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(:event_id), event = :event, staff_booking_id = :staff_booking_id, is_read = :is_read, priority = :priority;";

        $result = $this->db->prepare($q);
        $result = $result->execute($data_test);
```

Comment: Tip: Don't put `;` in queries run through an API like PDO. That's a delimiter used for interactive environments to indicate the end of the query. That's done implicitly in the `prepare()` function.

Comment: For the life of me, I can't remember which link on php.net talks about this but it does have something to do with your reusing the same named placeholders again. It has something to do with "emulation", if my memory serves me right. There is someone who knows this here, that I know. Edit: About *"(I'm trying to do this without using bindParam as in example #2 here)"* - The page you referenced doesn't mention the use of `ON DUPLICATE KEY`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I've seen issues with using the same place-holder twice, and it may depend on if your driver supports it or not. Emulation may fix the issue.

Comment: @tadman That's what I meant, thanks.

Comment: Note: I added the "on-duplicate-key" tag, since I thought it was relevant.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? Is the issue with the place holders on duplicate?

Comment: @AdamRoberts [About your comment, reload mine...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60217542/prepared-statements-sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number#comment106512726_60217542). I edited it before seeing your comment.

Comment: I'd have thought the same placeholders would have just bound the values in the same way. Is there a way to do this without making it difficult to do so dynamically?

Comment: @tadman (and Adam). I found [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432084/pdo-parameterized-query-reuse-named-placeholders) and closed the question. That is what I meant earlier. I Google'd the right words.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I've taken a read and added `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,` but I'm now getting the error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'event = 'TESTESTEST', staff_booking_id = '27255', is_read = 'yes', priority = 'm' at line 3`
 I can't see any issue with this, any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it's because `EVENT` is a mysql reserved word. Either rename it to one that isn't reserved or use ticks around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commentented by FunkFortyNiner and tadman, it is possible that the issue comes from the fact that you are reusing the same placeholder.

Actually the MySQL syntax does not require you to reuse the named parameter: you can use the `VALUES()` to refer to the values initially passed for `INSERT`.

Also, your attempt to update `event_id` using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` does not seem right; I am unsure that this is valid syntax - and anyway, if this is the primary key of table, then you don't want to update it.

Finally, as pinpointed by FunkFortyNiner, `event` is [a reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), so it needs to be quoted.

```
$q = 
    "INSERT INTO events(
        event_id, 
        `event`, 
        staff_booking_id, 
        is_read, 
        priority
    ) 
    VALUES(
        :event_id, 
        :event, 
        :staff_booking_id, 
        :is_read, 
        :priority
    ) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        `event` = VALUES(`event`),
        staff_booking_id = VALUES(staff_booking_id),
        is_read = VALUES(is_read), 
        priority = VALUES(priority)";
```

Comment: There's also the thing about `EVENT` being reserved in mysql. I added [a note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60217542/prepared-statements-sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number?noredirect=1#comment106513064_60217542) about that under their question in comments, in response to theirs above it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: ah yes, you are right, did not spot that. I edited my answer accordingly... Thanks.

Comment: It also eluded me earlier till I noticed [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60217542/prepared-statements-sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number#comment106512999_60217542) about having a new error. That's what made me take another (closer) look at their code. Edit: You know; I'm glad you managed to put in an answer even after I closed it.